# MongoDB Aggregated Count

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have this structure

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId( "42342342hj234h2j4h23j4h32j" ),
    "email" : "some@email.com",
    "points" : "5"
}
```

I have around 100k+ documents.

How can I come up with this result:

```
{
    "frequency"   : 5
    "email_count" : 100
}
{
    "frequency"   : 4
    "email_count" : 24
}
{
    "frequency"   : 3
    "email_count" : 32
}
```

where frequency depicts how many times the an email appeared in the set and the email count depicts how many emails have that particular frequency
(ex. some@email.com appeared 5x in the data set so as some1@email.com where as frequency = 5,email_count = 2)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this sort of result using [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) and the use of a "double" [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) phase:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$email",
        "frequency": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$frequency",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

So when you think this through, the first stage is "counting" the occurrences of the same "email" address in the collection, this is the "frequency".

The second stage, then "groups" on the same occurrences of this "frequency" value and "counts" the number of times that same value was found.

Familiarize yourself with aggregation concepts and the [available operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/). It will be well worth it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for pointing that out. Since I'm very new to MongoDb. Looks like I have to do more readings